# expand delimited text over multiplie lines

Tags: string, vim

I am looking for a power vim tip - to expand specially formatted text over multiple lines.

say i have `Bill | 12 | Male | Blue | right | Pay 150k`

i'd like it to expand (after some vim magic) to

```
Name: Bill
Age: 12
Gender: Male
Eyes: Blue
Right Handed: True
Pay 150k (we Rec 150k)
```

I have found multi-line abbreviations, but i cannot see how to make them more general, nor how to handle the True / False case, or the more complex formatting in the last row -- note that if the input string was `... | Rec 150k` the last output row would read `Rec 150k (we Pay 150k)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick hack:

```
function! Fmt(str)
    let parts = split(a:str, '\v\s*\|\s*', 1)
    if len(parts) == 6
        let parts[4] = parts[4] ==? 'right' ? 'true' : 'false'
        let parts[5] = substitute(parts[5], '\v.*Pay\s+(.+)', '\1 (we Rec \1)', '')
        let hdr = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Eyes', 'Right Handed', 'Pay']
        call map(parts, 'hdr[v:key] . ": " . v:val')
        return join(parts, "\n")
    else
        return a:str
    endif
endfunction
```

Write the above to a file, say `fmt.vim`, source it (`:so fmt.vim`) from the file you want to edit, then run `%s/.*/\=F(submatch(0))/`.

A different approach:

```
:%s/\v^([^|]+) \| ([^|]+) \| ([^|]+) \| ([^|]+) \| ([^|]+) \| ([^|]+)/Name: \1\rAge: \2\rGender: \3\rEyes: \4\rRight Handed: \5\r\6/
:%s/\v^Right Handed: \zsright/true/
:%g!/^Right Handed: true/ s/\v^Right Handed: \zs.*/false/
:%s/\v^Pay\zs\s+(.*)/: \1 (we Rec \1)/
```